# How to Print Random Words from a Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, text-files

I have a text file with 2000 words, one word on each line. I'm trying to create a code that prints out two random words from the textfile on the same line every 10 seconds. The beginning part of my text file is shown below:

```
slip
melt
true
therapeutic
scarce
visitor
wild
tickle
.
.
.
```

The code that I've written is:

```
from time import sleep
import random

my_file = open("words.txt", "r")


i = 1
while i > 0:
    number_1 = random.randint(0, 2000)
    number_2 = random.randint(0, 2000)
    word_1 = my_file.readline(number_1)
    word_2 = my_file.readline(number_2)
    print(word_1.rstrip() + " " + word_2.rstrip())
    i += 1
    sleep(10)
```

When I execute the code instead of printing two random words it starts printing all the words in order from the top of the text. I'm not sure why this is happening since number_1 and number_2 are inside the loop so every time two words print number_1 and number_2 should be changed to two other random numbers. I don't think replacing number_1 and number_2 outside of the loop will work either since they'll be fixed to two values and the code will just keep on printing the same two words. Does anyone know what I can do to fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline()` doesn't take any parameters and just returns the next line in your file input*. Instead, try to create a list using `readlines()`, then choose randomly from that list. So here, you'd make `word_list = my_file.readlines()`, then choose random elements from `word_list`.

***Correction:** `readline()` does take a parameter of the number of bytes to read. The documentation for the function doesn't seem to explicitly state this. Thanks E. Ducateme!

Comment: @Dan Waxman ... minor correction ... `.readline()` does take a parameter, but most people don't use it. The documentation for `.readline()` is not explicitly clear, but it says: `examplefile.readline(size=-1, /)`. Putting a non-negative size into the method will return that number of bytes from the current line.

Comment: @E.Ducateme Thank you! I had checked the IO documentation briefly before posting and didn't see any arguments listed, which confused me as to how his code worked at all. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`my_file.readline(number_1)` does not do what you want. The argument for readline is the max size in bytes of a line you can read rather than the position of the line in the file.

As the other answer mentioned, a better approach is to first read the lines into a list and then randomly select words from it:

```
from time import sleep
import random

my_file = open("words.txt", "r")
words = my_file.readlines()

i = 1
while i > 0:
    number_1 = random.randint(0, 2000)
    number_2 = random.randint(0, 2000)
    word_1 = words[number_1]
    word_2 = words[number_2]
    print(word_1.rstrip() + " " + word_2.rstrip())
    i += 1
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: A minor improvement would also be to simply use `word_1 = random.choice(words)` to pick a random word, instead of doing the multi-step process of using `random.randint()` to pick an integer and then funneling that integer in as an index to find a word at that index position in the list. This was not the OP's question, but including it as a nuance.

Comment: If you want to avoid picking the same word twice (RNGs can do that) then either check that the two numbers are not equal, or use something like `number_1 = random.randint(0, 2000)` and `number_2 = (number_1 + random.randint(0, 1999)) % 2000`